Writing predominant class of polygons on overlaying polygon in QGIS
In QGIS I have multiple buildings with different classes (municipal, private, industry) within a building block. I need to get the majority of the class within a building block and write this data on the building block.
How to do this?


What have you tried ? Are you looking for a QGIS-expression ?

I tried the overlapping feature but this does not give me the majority within in building block,

Try the following expression for labelling:
array_majority(
    overlay_intersects(
        layer:='buildings', -- the layer with building
        expression:="class" -- the field with different classes
        )
    )[0]

It is based on two functions: overlay_intersects and array_majority.
